# How do I create a C# app that can have parameters passed into it via a PHP web service?

Tags: c#, php, .net

I have a C# console app that is always open, holding a often-needed large file into memory (for quickest access).

I have a PHP web page that gets called often, and I need this PHP page to call into the C# app with a parameter such as a path to an image file. For example, I need to pass "c:\images\example.jpg" to the C# app.

Once the C# app gets the file path parameter passed in, it should do some work.

What is the proper way to make a C# app accept outside calls without opening a new instance of the console app every time? Make it a service in Windows? Or some other way?

Comment: Based on your information, a Windows service would probably be the most logical implementation. Or possibly a web service so this service can run independently from the PHP application.

Comment: A web service would make sense here, wcf or web api for c#. They are built to accept calls from other appplications.

Comment: What type of data are you accessing that warrants keeping the file open?  What kind of work is occurring when you pass the parameter to the C# portion?  It seems unusual to keep the file open constantly.

Comment: It's an extremely large file that would take a long time to load if opening each time. It contains data sets used in image comparison and matching for 100,000+ images.